# vim (gvim) marking occurrences on the vertical bar?

Tags: linux, vim, eclipse, text-editors, gvim

When I search for a string, vim(gvim) highlights all the occurrences, which is great. But is there a way to show the occurrences with markers on the vertical bar on the right hand side, so if I click on the marker on the vertical bar, the editor can scroll automatically to the screen that contains the occurrence. Eclipse does it really nicely, but I haven't found such feature for vim(gvim)

I am not sure if vim(gvim) has this feature at all. If the answer is no, are there other Linux text editors that are free, have this feature, and are able to open large files ( >20M. A lot of editors can open such large files, but they simply freeze the computer, like Eclipse) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you perform your search?

```
:vim foo % | copen
```

opens a list of matches in the quickfix window. See `:help quickfix`.

The quickfix window doesn't appear on the right and there's no such thing as a "right column" in Vim but you can move it to the right with `<C-w>L` if you want. This doesn't seem very practical but it's doable. I don't know of a plugin or a native way to do *exactly* what you want.

The command above, coupled with `:cn` and `:cp` is very effective.

Answer (score 1):

I've written the [Buffersaurus plug-in](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3620) to do this.